# Creating libraries out of scripts (with alert cond) and importing them by another script

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

In pine script ver5, how can I Create libraries out of existing ver4/3 scripts (each with alert cond) and import them by another script (in a different layout).

For example:
3 layouts.
3 scripts (first 2 scripts have 2 alert conditions). Each script is in its own layout.

The third script is in the third layout.

*I would like to convert the two first scripts to libraries (With their alert conditions). Following that, i would like to import those scripts (libraries now) on the third script (in the third layout), and use their 4 alert conditios.

Thanks

Comment: You need to convert v3/4 scripts into v5 using the api references.

Comment: I suggest don't use `alertcondition` (it is prohibited in libraries) but use `alert` function. Last one have all possibilities that first one has and more over.